# Add files to sub-folder using composer archive

Tags: php, composer-php, zip, archive

I use `composer archive` command to archive my PHP e-commerce plugin to a zip file. It works well but I have one issue: it does not create a sub-folder within the archive which makes it incompatible with web installer on targeted platform.

Current zip structure:

- plugin.zip

  - file1.php
  - file2.php
  - config.yml

Desired zip structure:

- plugin.zip

  - plugin-folder

    - file1.php
    - file2.php
    - config.yml

Is there a way to achieve such result using `composer archive`? If not, I am open for alternatives.